# How do you share a link to a question?

Tags: support

I see there are badges for sharing a link to a question that is very popular. How do you share the link so that the site knows you did indeed actually share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

documented here

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

[image]